# Java 8 variable scope in lambda (Spark specific)

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda, scope

I would like to fill a map with a String as key and Row as value, my code:

```
private Map<String,Row> getMapFromDataset(Dataset<Row> dataset, List<String> mapColumns) {
    Map<String, Row> map = new HashMap<>();
    dataset.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) row ->
        map.put(getKey(mapColumns,row),row) //This works
    );
    return map; //Map is empty when returning!
}
```

My getKey() method (although i think is not the cause of the issue):

```
private String getKey(List<String> mapColumns, Row row) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(256);
    for(String col : mapColumns){
      sb.append((String)row.getAs(col));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Although it compiles and runs without errors, the map is always empty.
What i have noticed is that if i check the size of the map right after the first insertion, the map has size 1, so the items insertion works, but the returned map is empty
I also read that variables used within lambda should be final, this might explains the problem.
Any hint?

Comment: The dataset is not empty

Answer (score 1):

I found out that map initialization happens in Driver, while the lambdas `foreach` is sent to executors.

Comment: Probably that's what it is not a good idea to mutate objects inside a lambda

Comment: Yes, but this will force me to get the rows out of the dataset, either via 'toLocalIterator()' or 'collectAsList()' making this enormously slow and with unnecessary garbage.